# The Variance Covariance Matrix of an Estimator Stacking Two OLS Estimators

Tags: variance, least-squares, covariance, covariance-matrix

I am looking for how to derive the variance covariance matrix (henceforth, VCOV) of an estimator stacking two OLS estimators.

Suppose that we have two OLS estimators:
$$\hat{\alpha}\sim N(\alpha,\;\sigma^2_\alpha) \\
\hat{\beta}\sim N(\beta,\;\sigma^2_\beta)$$
for the following simple linear models
$$Y_i=X_i'\alpha+u_i,\qquad i=1, \ldots,\;N_\alpha \\
Z_j=W_j'\beta+e_j,\qquad j=1,\ldots,\;N_\beta
$$

In this situation, I am wondering if it is possible we can know the VCOV of $\hat{\gamma}=[\hat{\alpha}',\;\hat{\beta}']'$

If the $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are estimated from the same sample, the variance can be obtained easily by a system OLS.

However, the point is that $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are estimated by using **different** samples that have of course different sample size.

Is there any way to get the VCOV of $\hat{\gamma}?$

Comment: If the samples are different and independent then the estimators should be independent as well, unless there is some missing detail in the question

Comment: @J.Delaney So, you mean, the "off-diagonal" blocks of the variance of gamma should be a zero matrix.